# Fortes Report + Masks

Tags: delphi

Alguém sabe como posso formatar um CPF/CNPJ em um relatório no Fortes Report?

```
procedure TFRelMenLac.RLBand4BeforePrint(Sender: TObject; var PrintIt: Boolean);
var
  ltemp : string;
begin
  ltemp := dmretaguarda.qlac.fieldbyname('dccli').asstring;
  if length(ltemp) = 11 then
    begin
      rlldccli.Caption := 'CPF: ';
      //RLDBText29.DisplayMask := '000.000.000-00';

      RLDBText29.Text := copy(ltemp, 1,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp, 4,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp, 7,3)+'-'+copy(ltemp, 10,2);
    end
  else
    begin
      rlldccli.Caption := 'CNPJ: ';
      RLDBText29.Text := copy(ltemp, 1,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp, 4,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp,7,3)+'/'+copy(ltemp, 10,4)+'-'+copy(ltemp, 14,2);
    end;
      //RLDBText29.DisplayMask := '000.000.000/0000-00';
```

Tirando as áreas comentadas, eu tentei com o `Copy`, mas sem sucesso, alguma ideia?

----- Edit -----

```
 DMRetaguarda.QLac.close;
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.sql.clear;
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.SQL.Add('SELECT relinm.mattec, relinm.nmtec, relinm.nmequip, relinm.num_os, relinm.num_sel, relinm.dtpront, relinm.marca, relinm.modelo, relinm.matric, relinm.peso, relinm.num_lac, relinm.numinm,');
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.SQL.Add('cliente.razaosocial, cliente.cidade as clcid, cliente.uf as cluf, cliente.rua as clru, cliente.bairro as clbr, cliente.cep as clcp, cliente.chave, CASE WHEN cliente.cgc <> '''' THEN cliente.cgc ELSE cliente.cpf END AS dccli ');
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.SQL.Add('FROM relinm, cliente WHERE relinm.codcli = cliente.chave AND relinm.dtpront BETWEEN :pini AND :pfim ORDER BY relinm.mattec, relinm.nmequip, relinm.dtpront');
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.ParamByName('pini').AsDate := StrToDateTime(
    MaskEdit1.Text);
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.ParamByName('pfim').AsDate := StrToDateTime(
    MaskEdit2.Text);
  DMRetaguarda.QLac.open;
```

---- Edit2 ----

```
  if length(DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').AsString) = 11 then
  begin
    rlldccli.Caption := 'CPF: ';
    DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').EditMask := '999.999.999-99;0;_'
    //RLDBText29.DisplayMask := '000.000.000\-99;1;_';
    //RLDBText29.Text := copy(ltemp, 1,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp, 4,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp, 7,3)+'-'+copy(ltemp, 10,2);
  end
  else
  begin
    rlldccli.Caption := 'CNPJ: ';
    DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').EditMask := '99.999.999/9999-99;0;_';
    //RLDBText29.Text := copy(ltemp, 1,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp, 4,3)+'.'+copy(ltemp,7,3)+'/'+copy(ltemp, 10,4)+'-'+copy(ltemp, 14,2);
    //RLDBText29.DisplayMask := '000.000.000\0000-99;1;_';
  end;
```

Segue o meu QLac. Alguma ideia?

Ficou assim meu codigo porem fica todo embaralhado em alguns campos, ou seja, segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que pelo formato da pra entender que ficou errado, porem não é em todos, muitos ficam certos, alguma ideia de como proceder?

Comment: Alguem? Alguma ideia? @Caputo

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, alguma ideia?

Comment: Você pode implementar isso no GetText do TField ou Setar a máscara para o TField, já tentou?

Comment: @Caputo, tentei não cara :/, tem algum exemplo de como faria isso?

Comment: Por favor, adicione na pergunta o trecho onde a query `dtmretaguarda.qlac` é aberta para geração do relatório e o relatório é executado. Daí coloco o exemplo bem onde deveria ficar.

Comment: @Caputo, desculpa a demora, eu estava doente, irei postar assim que possivel. Valeu

Comment: @Caputo, segue minha query. Valeu, aguardo retorno.

Comment: Que componente Query você está usando?

Comment: @wesleyluan, TZQuery, do componente ZEOS.

Comment: @wesleyluan, coloquei a imagem e o codigo após editado.

Comment: Quando você altera a máscara do campo que é CPF o tamanho do mesmo não é mais 11, o campo passa a ter pontos e traço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Senhores, consegui resolver este problema com a ajuda do Wesley.

O único problema era o momento em que estava pegando os valores, o Fortes tem 2 etapas, Preparar e Mostrar... então, no meu código acima, estava mostrando depois de pegar os valores cpf/cnpj, e antes de mostrar o relatório, consequentemente o problema estava no `EVENTO`.

Então, tudo que fiz foi colocar no `evento do relatório` chamado, `OnDataRecord`, segue abaixo:

```
procedure TFRelMenLac.RLReport1DataRecord(Sender: TObject; RecNo,
  CopyNo: Integer; var Eof: Boolean; var RecordAction: TRLRecordAction);
begin
  if length(DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').AsString) = 11 then
  begin
    rlldccli.Caption := 'CPF: ';
    DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').EditMask := '999.999.999-99;0;_';
  end;
  if length(DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').AsString) = 14 then
  begin
    rlldccli.Caption := 'CNPJ: ';
    DMRetaguarda.QLac.FieldByName('dccli').EditMask := '99.999.999/9999-99;0;_';
  end;
end;
```

E pronto, funcionou feito mágica, obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui eu faço o seguinte, no *AfterOpen* do componente **Query** eu determino a máscara do próprio **TField**.

```
DataSet.FieldByName('CNPJ').EditMask := '99.999.999/9999-99;0;_';
DataSet.FieldByName('CPF').EditMask := '999.999.999-99;0;_';
```

Comment: Cara, quase deu certo, só que eu fiz as alterações coloquei para pegar CPF quando for CPF, e CNPJ quando for CNPJ, porém, algumas áreas ficaram trocadas, ou seja, cpf no cnpj, e cnpj no cpf...

Comment: O que você pode fazer é deixar um campo para CPF e outro para CGC mesmo, retirando o case do SQL e colocar um label para cada campo na mesma posição no relatório. Pois sempre ou um ou outro estará vazio.